# How to use eval for a variable inside a for in using Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, for-loop

When I try doing this:

```
a={0..10}
for i in $a
  do 
  echo $i
done
```

The output is just: {0..10}

Comment: Brace expansion doesn't work like that. If you look inside a all it will contain is the literal string `{0..10}` so obviously the loop won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of many situations when the traditional tool, `seq`, is more useful than bash's brace notation:

```
a=$(seq 0 10)
for i in $a
  do 
  echo $i
done
```

The above produces:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

An additional advantage of `seq` is that it works with variables, something that bash's braces won't do.  For example:

```
$ count=5
$ seq 0 $count
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Contrast the above with:

```
$ echo {0..$count}
{0..5}
```

The above failed because bash's brace notation does not accept variables for arguments.

#### Mac OSX

`seq` is available on OSX for versions 10.8+ and maybe also 10.7.  On older versions, the similar, but not identical, BSD tool `jot` can be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf -v a "%d " {0..10}
for i in $a
do 
  echo $i
done
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
for i in $(eval "echo $a"); do echo $i; done
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

But better (safer) than `eval` alternative in BASH is this arithmetic direecitve:

```
for ((i=0; i<=10; i++)); do echo $i; done
```

Comment: For the first one it is safer to just do `a=$(echo {0..10})`

Comment: But if OP already has `a={0..10}` then `echo $(echo $a)` won't work

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work if you do

```
a=$(echo {0..10})
```

Instead of `a={0..10}`, which will be interpreted as `a='{0..10}'` literally.